# Javascript code for detecting tab or browser closing

Tags: javascript

I want a `javascript` code snippet which will detect while closing the tab or closing the browser and should not activate event when go to other link or download any file any idea ? I saw there are lot of threads but didn't get the solution i tried this

```
a)
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
      var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

      (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
      return confirmationMessage;                            //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
    });
b)
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Do you really want to close?";
};
```

but its breaking other functionality(downloading file on click of anchor).
I shouldn't be triggered when browser get refresh or opening link or downloading any file.Any Idea on this?